# Символическая ссылка linux

Tags: linux

Есть каталог сайта

```
mysite.com
 --public_html
 --www 
 -- и другие.
```

Нужно, что бы папка www стала символической ссылкой для public_html, то есть при обращении к www открывало public_html.

Использование на примиер такого формата не подходи

```
ln -s /home/admin/web/mysite.com/public_html /home/admin/web/mysite.com/www
```

Так как создает ссылки этих папок внутри их.
Возможно кто то сможет поделиться здесь кодом на заметку.
Спасибо!

Comment: читать документацию `man ln`

Comment: Спасибо, ознакомился с документацией

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Сначала удали папку www, потом делай туда ссылку. Так как папка существует ln кладет ссылку внутрь

Comment: Спасибо, при прочтении документации почти дошел до этого.
Ваш совет сработал, благодарю